# How to get OpenCL working with AMD GPU on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, 18.04

I have tried several attempts but without success. AMDGPU-PRO 17.40, 17.50, ROCm, Oibaf PPA, Kernel 4.16 and something more, but nothing makes OpenCL working with the AMD card and clinfo never gives right results.

Can I only wait the next AMDGPU-PRO driver compatible with Ubuntu 18.04 or could I do something different?

Comment: Same here, tried all of these and more. please @ me if you figure it out. My hardware is GL702ZC, supposed to be supported by AMD.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install their experimental driver from here:

https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Radeon-Software-for-Linux-18.20-Early-Preview-Release-Notes.aspx

Hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same boat - for completeness here is the thread I started. 
@Mods, please consolidate if it makes sense to do so.

[Intel/AMD Hybrid graphics Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038271/intel-amd-hybrid-graphics-ubuntu-18-04)