# What configuration could cause partial driver failure in Xubuntu Bionic with the AMD GPU Pro drivers?

Tags: drivers, graphics, amdgpu, amdgpu-pro

I have a problem with Xubuntu Bionic (18.04.3) running on a Dell Precision 7530 with an AMD Radeon Pro WX 4150 video device. I recently installed the AMD GPU Pro driver from [this location](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-rad-lin-19-30-unified), specifically the file `amdgpu-pro-19.30-934563-ubuntu-18.04.tar.xz`.

### What's working

- Encryption login screen works
- X works fine on the laptop display
- Dock-connected displays (using the WD19DC dock)

### What's NOT working

- HDMI output on the laptop
- Mini-DP output on the laptop
- OpenGL
- Many Qt apps (probably because OpenGL is broken)

Specifically, `xrandr` reports that it knows about the HDMI and DisplayPort connections on the laptop, but nothing is recognized when attached to those ports.

Also, nothing seems to work within the OpenGL framework. Output of `glxinfo`:

```
name of display: :0.0
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig
```

Output of `glxgears`:

```
Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual
```

### Debugging details

Relevant lines of `lspci -vv` showing the Intel integrated graphics and the AMD graphics:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e9b (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Dell Device 0831
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 130
        Region 0: Memory at b3000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Region 2: Memory at 60000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Region 4: I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
        [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Baffin [Radeon Pro WX 4130/4150] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Dell Baffin [Polaris11]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 143
    Region 0: Memory at 4100000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4G]
    Region 2: Memory at 4080000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=2M]
    Region 4: I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Region 5: Memory at b4200000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Expansion ROM at b4240000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

Output of `dmesg | grep -i amdgpu`:

```
[    2.094881] [drm] amdgpu kernel modesetting enabled.
[    2.094883] [drm] amdgpu version: 5.0.73.19.30
[    2.097461] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[    2.475623] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: BAR 2: releasing [mem 0x80000000-0x801fffff 64bit pref]
[    2.475624] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: BAR 0: releasing [mem 0x70000000-0x7fffffff 64bit pref]
[    2.475646] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0x4100000000-0x41ffffffff 64bit pref]
[    2.475651] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: BAR 2: assigned [mem 0x4080000000-0x40801fffff 64bit pref]
[    2.475674] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: VRAM: 4096M 0x000000F400000000 - 0x000000F4FFFFFFFF (4096M used)
[    2.475675] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: GART: 256M 0x000000FF00000000 - 0x000000FF0FFFFFFF
[    2.475868] [drm] amdgpu: 4096M of VRAM memory ready
[    2.475869] [drm] amdgpu: 15796M of GTT memory ready.
[    2.477995] amdgpu: [powerplay] hwmgr_sw_init smu backed is polaris10_smu
[    3.151808] [drm:hwss_edp_wait_for_hpd_ready [amdgpu]] *ERROR* hwss_edp_wait_for_hpd_ready: wait timed out!
[    3.755912] [drm:hwss_edp_wait_for_hpd_ready [amdgpu]] *ERROR* hwss_edp_wait_for_hpd_ready: wait timed out!
[    4.177658] [drm] Initialized amdgpu 3.33.0 20150101 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 1
[   14.269498] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: GPU pci config reset
[   68.615509] [drm:hwss_edp_wait_for_hpd_ready [amdgpu]] *ERROR* hwss_edp_wait_for_hpd_ready: wait timed out!
[   69.223488] [drm:hwss_edp_wait_for_hpd_ready [amdgpu]] *ERROR* hwss_edp_wait_for_hpd_ready: wait timed out!
```

Here's the output of `grep -i "glx\|amdgpu" Xorg.0.log`:

```
[    70.624] (**) ModulePath set to "/opt/amdgpu-pro/lib/xorg/modules,/opt/amdgpu/lib/xorg/modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    70.643] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    70.644] (II) Loading /opt/amdgpu-pro/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    70.651] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    70.651] (II) Applying OutputClass "AMDgpu" to /dev/dri/card1
[    70.651]    loading driver: amdgpu
[    70.651] (==) Matched amdgpu as autoconfigured driver 0
[    70.651] (II) LoadModule: "amdgpu"
[    70.652] (II) Loading /opt/amdgpu/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/amdgpu_drv.so
[    70.653] (II) Module amdgpu: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    70.656] (II) Applying OutputClass "AMDgpu" to /dev/dri/card1
[    70.656]    loading driver: amdgpu
[    70.656] (==) Matched amdgpu as autoconfigured driver 0
[    70.656] (II) LoadModule: "amdgpu"
[    70.656] (II) Loading /opt/amdgpu/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/amdgpu_drv.so
[    70.656] (II) Module amdgpu: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    70.656] (II) AMDGPU: Driver for AMD Radeon:
    All GPUs supported by the amdgpu kernel driver
[    70.675] (II) AMDGPU(G0): [KMS] Kernel modesetting enabled.
[    71.254] (==) AMDGPU(G0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[    71.254] (II) AMDGPU(G0): Pixel depth = 24 bits stored in 4 bytes (32 bpp pixmaps)
[    71.254] (==) AMDGPU(G0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    71.254] (==) AMDGPU(G0): RGB weight 888
[    71.254] (II) AMDGPU(G0): Using 8 bits per RGB (8 bit DAC)
[    71.254] (--) AMDGPU(G0): Chipset: "AMD Radeon (TM) Pro WX Series" (ChipID = 0x67e8)
[    71.400] (II) AMDGPU(G0): glamor X acceleration enabled on AMD Radeon (TM) Pro WX Series
[    71.400] (II) AMDGPU(G0): glamor detected, initialising EGL layer.
[    71.400] (==) AMDGPU(G0): TearFree property default: auto
[    71.400] (II) AMDGPU(G0): Output eDP-1-1 has no monitor section
[    71.400] (II) AMDGPU(G0): Output DisplayPort-1-3 has no monitor section
[    71.400] (II) AMDGPU(G0): Output DisplayPort-1-4 has no monitor section
[    71.400] (II) AMDGPU(G0): Output DisplayPort-1-5 has no monitor section
[    71.400] (II) AMDGPU(G0): Output HDMI-A-1-1 has no monitor section
[    71.401] (II) AMDGPU(G0): EDID for output eDP-1-1
[    71.401] (II) AMDGPU(G0): EDID for output DisplayPort-1-3
[    71.401] (II) AMDGPU(G0): EDID for output DisplayPort-1-4
[    71.401] (II) AMDGPU(G0): EDID for output DisplayPort-1-5
[    71.401] (II) AMDGPU(G0): EDID for output HDMI-A-1-1
[    71.401] (II) AMDGPU(G0): mem size init: gart size :3dadf1000 vram size: s:ffad1000 visible:bfc1cc00
[    71.401] (II) AMDGPU(G0): Video RAM: 4188996 kByte
[    71.401] (==) AMDGPU(G0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[    71.401] (==) AMDGPU(G0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    71.401] (II) AMDGPU(G0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[    71.401] (II) AMDGPU(G0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: radeonsi
[    71.401] (II) AMDGPU(G0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: radeonsi
[    71.401] (II) AMDGPU(G0): Front buffer pitch: 4096 bytes
[    71.402] (==) AMDGPU(G0): Backing store enabled
[    71.402] (II) AMDGPU(G0): Direct rendering enabled
[    71.451] (II) AMDGPU(G0): Use GLAMOR acceleration.
[    71.451] (II) AMDGPU(G0): Acceleration enabled
[    71.451] (==) AMDGPU(G0): DPMS enabled
[    71.451] (==) AMDGPU(G0): Silken mouse enabled
[    71.510] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[    71.510] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI2 capable
[    71.510] (EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
[    71.510] (II) GLX: no usable GL providers found for screen 0
```

The last three lines of this indicate a potential problem.

When many Qt applications try to start, a **segfault** appears in `dmesg`, presumably because they expect OpenGL to work. Examples of broken apps: Wireshark, QDirStat, etc. Below is an example from when Wireshark tries to start:

```
[ 4574.568730] wireshark[12453]: segfault at 10 ip 00007f2ebfde6530 sp 00007ffdfeb2ea70 error 4 in libdrm_amdgpu.so.1.0.0[7f2ebfdde000+c000]
```

The console output of `wireshark`:

```
screen 0 does not appear to be DRI2 capable
screen 0 does not appear to be DRI2 capable
amdgpu_device_initialize: amdgpu_get_auth (1) failed (-1)
Segmentation fault
```

Here's the backtrace produced by `gdb wireshark` after the segfault:

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /usr/bin/wireshark 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7fffde8ad700 (LWP 14468)]
screen 0 does not appear to be DRI2 capable
screen 0 does not appear to be DRI2 capable
amdgpu_device_initialize: amdgpu_get_auth (1) failed (-1)

Thread 1 "wireshark" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fffdcde6530 in amdgpu_query_info () from /opt/amdgpu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_amdgpu.so.1
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fffdcde6530 in amdgpu_query_info () from /opt/amdgpu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_amdgpu.so.1
#1  0x00007fffd607654c in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/amdgpu_dri.so
#2  0x00007fffd6081248 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/amdgpu_dri.so
#3  0x00007fffd5e88678 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/amdgpu_dri.so
#4  0x00007fffd5eb388f in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/amdgpu_dri.so
#5  0x00007fffd51782c5 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/amdgpu_dri.so
#6  0x00007fffd5cd354c in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/amdgpu_dri.so
#7  0x00007fffd6073c7b in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/amdgpu_dri.so
#8  0x00007fffd5d9106e in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/amdgpu_dri.so
#9  0x00007fffd5d91576 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/amdgpu_dri.so
#10 0x00007fffd5d94709 in eglInitialize () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/amdgpu_dri.so
#11 0x00007fffdd87f3c4 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-egl-integration.so
#12 0x00007fffe2e5b369 in QXcbConnection::QXcbConnection(QXcbNativeInterface*, bool, unsigned int, char const*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#13 0x00007fffe2e5e7fe in QXcbIntegration::QXcbIntegration(QStringList const&, int&, char**) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#14 0x00007fffe31242ab in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so
#15 0x00007ffff04c3add in QPlatformIntegrationFactory::create(QString const&, QStringList const&, int&, char**, QString const&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
#16 0x00007ffff04d4922 in QGuiApplicationPrivate::createPlatformIntegration() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
#17 0x00007ffff04d545d in QGuiApplicationPrivate::createEventDispatcher() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
#18 0x00007fffeff20885 in QCoreApplicationPrivate::init() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#19 0x00007ffff04d6eef in QGuiApplicationPrivate::init() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
#20 0x00007ffff0c9c659 in QApplicationPrivate::init() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#21 0x00005555557f3ce1 in WiresharkApplication::WiresharkApplication(int&, char**) ()
#22 0x00005555556e7574 in main ()
```

### Possible explanations I've explored, but could still be it

- I have competing graphics driver files or packages
- I have a configuration file set incorrectly, somewhere
- Another installed/optional library is affecting the functionality of `amdgpu`
- Something else

I did not install [the Enterprise version of the drivers](https://www.amd.com/en/support/professional-graphics/radeon-pro/radeon-pro-wx-x100-series/radeon-pro-wx-4100) because they only support Ubuntu 18.04.2 and `dkms` will not build with the Linux 5 kernel (even the driver released last week).

I have tried two firmware-level configurations: with an without integrated graphics bypass. If bypass is disabled (normal mode), the Intel GPU and the AMD GPU are both able to drive. If discrete graphics bypass is enabled, the Intel GPU is bypassed and only the AMD GPU is enabled. While I have a different set of problems related to switching, the problems on this page affect both configurations.

Everything works fine in Windows 10, so I don't think it's a hardware issue.

Answer (score 2):

After many experiments (and completely fresh Ubuntu and Xubuntu installs), I have found a workaround: disabling switchable graphics entirely. In the Precision 7530 firmware settings, I can turn off switchable graphics and use only the discrete card. When I do that, the OpenGL-related failures vanish as well as the crashing of Qt apps.

Direct Discrete mode (enabling the Intel chip but bypassing it) was insufficient. I had to turn off switching entirely, at which point the Intel VGA device no longer appears to Linux.

This is not exactly a solution, but it's a workaround, and it's better than the alternative.

**Edit**: Power usage is so much worse in this configuration. I get about half the battery life. It would still be great for this to work correctly with the Intel chip still enabled.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038271/intel-amd-hybrid-graphics-ubuntu-18-04, specifically PRIME technology can be used as a solution for hybrid graphics.

Comment: @YuzhanaE. I believe Prime is set up by default on Ubuntu with switchable graphics, and it did not help me get this solved. I'm still living with the workaround of having direct discrete mode enable.

Comment: [you’re right](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=AMDGPU-Intel-4.9-PRIME-Ex-Patch).
Anyway, in my case I got Intel/AMD working on kernel 5.3 with the latest official amdgpu drivers. [The steps I followed](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1947001).