# Switch Intel to AMD Radeon 530 graphic in lenovo V330-15k

Tags: graphics, radeon, intel

I can't switch my Intel graphic to AMD Radeon 530 in Ubuntu 18.04.04 LTS.

What should I do with that? should I switch to windows or it can be fixed?

I searched much but no usable answer found.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install AMD graphic drivers on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066105/how-to-install-amd-graphic-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Answer (score 0):

If you have amdgpu drivers installed as [suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066105/how-to-install-amd-graphic-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04) in comment, then you could try the next:

- Output listproviders:

  ```
  $ xrandr --listproviders
  Providers: number : 2
  Provider 0: id: 0x64 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 3 
  outputs: 2 associated providers: 1 name:modesetting
  Provider 1: id: 0x3f cap: 0x4, Source Offload crtcs: 0 outputs: 0 
  associated providers: 1 name:HAINAN @ pci:0000:0a:00.0
  ```
- Switch to provider1 (`id` and `cap` values):

  ```
  $ xrandr --setprovideroffloadsink 0x3f 0x64
  ```
- Run game, steam or whatever you want with amdgpu:

  ```
  $ DRI_PRIME=1 steam
  ```

[Reference](https://askubuntu.com/a/1098654/925971)